# How do I project my WMS tilelayer in leaflet if I want it to display as an overlay on my basemap if they have different EPSG?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, wfs, leaflet

So my basemap is a world Mercator projection and in wfs format and I'm trying to put a WMS overlay in a different projection over it? Leaflet's API didn't give me much info on changing the epsg so is it even possible?

Comment: Just request the WMS in the SRS of your base map - GeoServer will handle the reprojection for you.

Comment: @iant can you provide an example of how to do this with Leaflet? I understand in GeoServer's WMS we just append something like `&srsName=epsg:3857` to the URL, but how can we pass this into Leaflet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet supports PseudoMercator projection out-of-the-box (EPSG:3857).  You can force Leaflet to use a few other projections listed [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs) in the documentation.  Don't worry, I found leaflet's API documentation kind of 'meh'.  Documentation by programmers...

World Mercator is supported with a easy to use method, lucky you.

```
L.CRS.EPSG3395
```

You just place that anywhere in the global scope of your script and it should set your projection for you map.

Additionally, there is a plugin for leaflet that can allow you to use more 'uncommon' projections.  [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet)

Note: It doesn't appear that Leaflet will tranform  your layer into another projection like ArcGIS or QGIS but will just take the data at face value and render it that way.  You will need to serve your data in the projection that your tell Leaflet to use.

Comment: Thx, I'm actually taking over a leaflet related project and I was able to find that bit of code, but the issue was that it was part of a minified library called leaf-custom.js and so the code is just one long horizontal line that won't wrap so I have to disseminate it.

Comment: Oh so the actual map implementation is an external, minified library?  If so, try just adding the projection line in the script body like you would if building the map yourself.  I *think* it would behave just the same.

Comment: Not exactly, certain configurations are being hard-coded within the external minified library, but there is a map implementation file and a few other files to render the views all part of a namespace that draws from the minified library so I have to figure out where to make modifications.

Answer (score 1):

In Leaflet 0.7 you can assign a different CRS to each WMS Layer by using its csr option.

```
var myLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(...);
myLayer.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG4326;
```

Comment: I have same requirement. The point is that is it possible to add wms layer with crs different than the map's crs?

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt to display the layer in projection 3395.
I determine the offset between the projections 3857 and 3395 in pxs _getReprojectOffset() and  redefine private functions _getTilePos(), _getTiledPixelBounds

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
    center: [51, 55],
    zoom: 12
});

L.TileLayer.EPSG3395 = L.TileLayer.extend({     
    _getReprojectOffset: function(latLng, zoom) {
        var mapProjectPoint = this._map.options.crs.latLngToPoint(latLng, zoom);
        var lyrProjectPoint = L.CRS.EPSG3395.latLngToPoint(latLng, zoom);   
        return lyrProjectPoint.subtract(mapProjectPoint);
    },
    
    _getTilePos: function (coords) {        
        var tileBounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);          
        var reprojOffset = this._getReprojectOffset(tileBounds._northEast, coords.z);
        return coords.scaleBy(this.getTileSize()).subtract(this._level.origin).subtract(reprojOffset);
    },

    _getTiledPixelBounds: function (center) {
        var map = this._map,
            mapZoom = map._animatingZoom ? Math.max(map._animateToZoom, map.getZoom()) : map.getZoom(),
            scale = map.getZoomScale(mapZoom, this._tileZoom),
            pixelCenter = map.project(center, this._tileZoom).floor(),
            halfSize = map.getSize().divideBy(scale * 2);
        
        var reprojOffset = this._getReprojectOffset(center, this._tileZoom).floor();
        return new L.Bounds(pixelCenter.subtract(halfSize), pixelCenter.add(halfSize).add(reprojOffset));
    }       
});


L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=yuor_token_key', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer.epsg3395 = function(templateUrl, options) {
    return new L.TileLayer.EPSG3395(templateUrl, options);
}

map.addLayer(L.tileLayer.epsg3395("https://coverage-map.megafon.ru/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?layers=3g"));
```

Comment: Using Proj4Leaflet plugin (https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) would be simpler (and preferred) solution.